# How can I restrict preg_replace_callback so that it replaces a limited number of expression matches?

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

An example of what I need:

```
$input = "bar bar bar bar bar";
$result = preg_replace_callback('bar', 'foo', $input); // And there must be some way to limit preg_replace_callback so that it replaces only the first 2 (for example) matches of the expression
echo $result;
```

Result: foo foo bar bar bar

Tried google it but didn't find anything. Sorry, I'm new to php.

Comment: Then being new to PHP, one should check the [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) API details to see that the function has other parameters available to help do exactly what you seek.

Comment: @PaulT. You are right, I did not notice that there is exactly what I need, thanks.